# Data frame r - multiple match code

Tags: r

I have two data frames that I want to connect.

First one is:

```
V1 <- c("AB1", "AB2", "AB3" ,"AB4" ,"AB5" ,"AB6" ,"AB7","AB6","AB9" ,"AB10")
df1 <- data.frame(V1)
```

Second one is:

```
V5 <- c("AB1","","","", "AB3", "AB4", "AB5", "AB6")
V6 <- c("AB","AB2","","AB", "", "AB", "", "AB")
V7 <- c("AB","AB","AB","", "AB", "", "AB", "AB")
V8 <- c(1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6)

df2 <- data.frame(V5,V6, V7, V8)
```

I try to look up V1 from df1 in df2 in V5, V6 and V7 columns and return V8 from df2 and also add column with yes (when df$V1 is in df2).

The desired result is:

```
V df1$V1    res df$V8   Yes/no
AB1        1            1
AB2        2            1
AB3        3            1
AB4        4            1
AB5        5            1
AB6        6            1
AB7                     0
AB6                     0
AB9                     0
AB10                    0
```

I have the below code but I can not get them working just for 3 columns from df2 at the same time?

```
df1$res[match(df2$V5,df1$V1, nomatch=0)] <- df2$V6[match(df2$V5,df1$V1, nomatch = 0)]
```

Comment: Where's the `df2` dataset? Why the value for `AB2` is 2? It's also associated with value 1. Why for `AB6` the `Yes/No` column is 0? Why `AB3` to `AB6` are not matched, when they exist in `df2`?

Comment: Please have a look now.

Comment: Why `AB3` has no match? It exists in both `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: Why in the desired output only the second row of `AB6` has a match? Your desired output doesn't match what you describe above.

Comment: @ AntosiosK fixed now

Comment: Better now :) But still there's a problem with `AB6` in your desired output. Now only the first row of `AB6` has a match.

Answer (score 1):

```
V1 <- c("AB1", "AB2", "AB3" ,"AB4" ,"AB5" ,"AB6" ,"AB7","AB6","AB9" ,"AB10")
df1 <- data.frame(V1, stringsAsFactors = F)

V5 <- c("AB1","","","", "AB3", "AB4", "AB5", "AB6")
V6 <- c("AB","AB2","","AB", "", "AB", "", "AB")
V7 <- c("AB","AB","AB","", "AB", "", "AB", "AB")
V8 <- c(1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6)
df2 = data.frame(V5,V6,V7,V8, stringsAsFactors = F)

library(tidyverse)

df2 %>%
  gather(v, V1, -V8) %>%           # reshape dataset
  select(-v) %>%                   # remove unecessary variable
  right_join(df1, by="V1") %>%     # join df1
  mutate(YesNo = ifelse(is.na(V8), 0, 1)) %>%   # create Yes/No variable
  distinct() %>%                   # select distinct rows
  select(V1, V8, YesNo)            # arrange columns

#     V1 V8 YesNo
# 1  AB1  1     1
# 2  AB2  2     1
# 3  AB3  3     1
# 4  AB4  4     1
# 5  AB5  5     1
# 6  AB6  6     1
# 7  AB7 NA     0
# 8  AB9 NA     0
# 9 AB10 NA     0
```

If you remove `distinct()` from the code you'll get all rows of `df1` (not the distinct rows).

Comment: @ AntosiosK thank you. final question what would be the code if columns in df1 and df2 have different names - say df$V1 is 'aaa'.

Comment: You'll have to use the names you have instead of `V1` and `V8`. Wherever you see `V1` in my code you should replace it with `aaa` and the same with `V8`